# CouchbaseLite in Android : Network Timeout

Tags: android, connection, timeout, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am using Couchbase Lite in my Android Application.
Now, I have to handle a situation when the server is not responding / down or the device is not connected somehow.
Being new, I am not sure how to handle such Connection Exception and probably show a toast or something.

Comment: How did you solved this?